# Camera access , permission denial

Tags: android

I already searched on stackoverflow and found very useful answers but none of them worked for me.
Iam trying to access the webcam of my laptop through the emulator from android studio.

This is my code :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                          MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath());
          startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        }
```

i also added the following permissions :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

i also enabled in avd the following settings :
Camera : `Front set to WebCam0` and `Back set to WebCam0`

The error i am getting is :

```
        java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { 
        act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera 
        (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{8f8626     
        3870:com.example.felix.eitimer/u0a57} (pid=3870, uid=10057) with
        revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

Maybe someone knows the answer, i find it quite strange since, EVERY tutorial about it, explains what i have tried so far.

Comment: Which Android system version are you emulating?

Comment: And the emulator as well? Try it on 22 (emulator), 6.0 has a different approach to permissions, you have to ask the user to grant you the camera permission.